# Partial views in Play exist?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.2

I haven't found any notion of partial views in Play Framework similar to Ruby on Rails's partial views. For example, if there is `layouts/main.scala.html` layout:

```
@(title: String)(content: => Html)(implicit flash: Flash)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>

    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="content">@content</section>
    </body>
</html>
```

And there is also `layouts/_footer.scala.html` "partial", how do I include `_footer` into `main`?
Is there anything similar in Play?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think RoR's partial views are overly complex.  The thing to remember about Play templates, as that they are essentially just functions that can be called directly from Scala code.  And also, Play templates are essentially Scala code.  That means, Play templates can be called from other Play templates.  So, just create another template called `footer.scala.html`, eg:

```
<footer>
   Powered by Play Framework
</footer>
```

And then call it from your main template, as you would invoke any other Scala function:

```
@(title: String)(content: => Html)(implicit flash: Flash)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section class="content">@content</section>
        @footer()
    </body>
</html>
```

Couldn't be easier.

Comment: how does Play know where @footer is defined?

Comment: @Alex In this case `@footer` would have to be defined in the `views.html` namespace, which is automatically imported for Play templates. If it instead resided in `app/views/common/footer.scala.html`, then it would instead be `common.footer()`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you're using Play 1.x or 2, but in Play 1, there are template tags - See http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.7/templates#inheritance

Answer (score 0):

I think what @Vidya wants to say is that you can do something like this:

In main.scala.html we add a variable named footer of type Html with a default value of empty:

```
   @(title: String, footer: Html = Html(""))(content: Html)

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <html>
        <head>
            <title>@title</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            @content
            @footer
        </body>
    </html>
```

And then in a page like index.scala.html we can do something like:

```
@(message: String)

@footer = {
    <footer>the footer!</footer>
}

@main("Welcome", footer) {
    the content!
}
```